# ARM Cortex-M Floating Point Multiply-Accumulate Cycle Time

Tags: arm, cortex-m, floating-point

According to the [ARM Cortex M4 technical manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Floating-Point-Unit/FPU-Functional-Description/FPU-instruction-set), a floating point multiply accumulate instruction (VMLA.F32) takes 3 cycles. However the separate multiply (VMUL.F32) and add (VADD.F32) instructions only take 1 cycle each. This would suggest that a multiple accumulate instruction is slower than just doing the two operations separately which seems rather strange.

Is this really the case, or am I overlooking something here?

The only reason I can think is that they included VMLA.F32 for compatibility reasons, but in that case, why is it not possibly to complete the instruction in two cycles?

Comment: This may be a confusion between latency and throughput. You obviously can't perform the Accumulate until the MPY is complete (so 3 CY latency is plausible). But if you can't push 1 MAC per cycle (throughput) somebody screwed up (or the MPU wasn't designed with DSP performance in mind). See also teh NOTES : if you MPY then ADD as separate instructions, the first instruction takes a second cycle.

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks - didn't see the note about the extra cycle for sequential arithmetic instructions. That makes more sense then as it means the MAC has a one cycle advantage in some situations. I wonder if anyone has insight into why the FPU works like this? It must be either something to do with post-formatting of the result or a data path bottleneck.

Comment: @Jon I'm not at all familiar with the ARM family design. (Stayed away from it.) But it is quite likely due to a "bubble" in the pipeline caused by the addition referencing a result from the multiplication without decent forwarding logic available. Personally, I think that's "dumb" and I'd not waste precious instruction space on a MAC instruction if I didn't have a forwarding mechanism. It's not rocket-science to add forwarding, but that depends on the pipeline stages, too. If they could add forwarding, I've no idea why they didn't. If they can't, then I've no idea why they bothered.

Comment: @jonk maybe it's binary compatibility with cortex-m7 cores or with the application processor cortex-a\* cores, or maybe it's a code density thing where you can simply funroll fixed-size vector-vector products and still get compact machine code (the Mac instruction is but 32 bit, I don't know whether that same density can be achieved with mul+add)

Answer (score 1):

The `vmla.f` instruction does `a += b*c`, specifically the destination register is the same as the accumulated value. This means we need to compare the `vadd.f` instruction when there is a dependency. In this case it takes 3 cycles, per the source below (for Cortex M7, but I presume it's similar for M4)

So when you add the dependency-free throughput of 1 cycle of the `vmul.f` instruction you get 4 cycles total, which is longer.

I couldn't find a source for the throughput of these instructions with data dependencies for the Cortex M4, but I found [this excellent page](https://www.quinapalus.com/cm7cycles.html) with data for the Cortex M7.

[image: Screenshot from quinapalus]